# capistrano rails app has parent folder in git

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

using cap '3.7.2' and rails 4.2. Our rails app in in git with a parent folder, so in the git repo there is parentfolder/app instead of app at the root. This causes cap to put my app in a sub folder in the release folder which messes everything up. Is there some easy way to tell cap to ignore the parent folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it!

set :repo_tree, 'mysubdir'